# Removing Columns and Rows with 'NA' Names from R Data Table

Tags: r

I have a table of Variants Data, giving the frequency of length variants with respect to associated SNPs:

```
          A    C    G    T <NA>
  -1      0   64    0   63    2
  -2      0    0    0    1    0
  0       2 5995    2 5704  203
  1       0   13    0   16    1
  <NA>    0   27    0   21    0
```

As you can see, there is both and  row and an  column. I want to remove these but seem to be struggling specifying these with script. I have tried the following, but this only returns the original table shown above:

```
    if(any(is.na(colnames(Data)))){
 -which(is.na(colnames(Data)))
}

if(any(is.na(rownames(Data)))){
  -which(is.na(rownames(Data)))
}

Data
```

Please could someone tell me either where my script is failing, or how I can go about removing the row and column?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your names are the literal string `"<NA>"`, then RonakShah's answer is first and correct.

If not, then try this:

```r
dat2[!is.na(rownames(dat2)), !is.na(colnames(dat2))]
#    y
# x   1 2 3 4
#   1 6 5 3 3
#   2 6 4 6 5
#   3 6 1 0 3
#   4 7 3 3 5
```

Data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(1:4, NA), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c(1:4, NA), size = 100, replace = TRUE))
dat2 <- table(dat, useNA = "always")
dat2
#       y
# x      1 2 3 4 <NA>
#   1    6 5 3 3    3
#   2    6 4 6 5    4
#   3    6 1 0 3    1
#   4    7 3 3 5    2
#   <NA> 4 7 4 4    5
```

Comment: So you mean OP's data is a `table` and not a dataframe?

Comment: It's a guess, tbh. Though the question does start with *"I have a table"*, and since it mentions *"frequency"*, I thought it a fair guess.

Comment: This worked a treat. Thank you so much: two days of banging my head against a wall finally at an end

Answer (score 1):

column names and rownames are stored as strings, so you cannot identify them with `is.na` :

```
df[rownames(df) != '<NA>', colnames(df) != '<NA>']

#   A    C G    T
#-1 0   64 0   63
#-2 0    0 0    1
#0  2 5995 2 5704
#1  0   13 0   16
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), C = c(64L, 0L, 5995L, 
13L, 27L), G = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), T = c(63L, 1L, 5704L, 16L, 
21L), `<NA>` = c(2L, 0L, 203L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("-1", "-2", "0", "1", "<NA>"))
```